# jquery if else statement doesnt work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am checking the variable `wal`, which I get from a PHP file with `json_encode`. If `wal`'s value is under 100, it should render a calendar where `selectable = false`. Else, it should render a calendar where `selectable = true`.

My code looks like this (`fullCalendar` is not included in this snippet):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (wal < "100") {
        alert (wal);
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            selectable: false,
        }
    });

    } else {
        alert (wal); 
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            selectable: true,}
        });   
    };
}
```

In one case, `war` = 120, so it should fire the `else` condition, but it still renders `selectable = false`.

Where is my mistake?

**Edit 1**

I changed  `if (wal < 100)` to  `if (parseInt(wal) < 100)`. With `wal` = 120, it jumps into the `else` statement. But if I change `war` to a lower number (like `wal` = 60) it still jumps into the `else` statement, bypassing the first statement.

Comment: Your mistake is comparing strings instead of numbers...

Comment: ok maybe this is the problem. I alert now alert(parseInt(wal)); and he alert = NaN! What NaN stands for?

Comment: `NaN` stands for "Not a Number".

Comment: ok he is NaN cuz the string is "120" how can i delete the " " chars?

Comment: `$.trim(" 120")` will return `"120"`.

Comment: i use wal = wal.replace(/"/g,''); Works greate. Thx guys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (wal < "100")
```

should be changed to

```
if (parseInt(wal, 10) < 100)
```

to properly compare numbers data types.

Comment: looks like `wal` is a string as well.  updated answer to parse that into an integer.

Comment: still jump into else :-(

Comment: [Always provide the radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Parameters) when using `parseInt()`

Comment: Yes. My Value is 120 so he go into else with <100 but for test purp i change 100 to 500 ( <500) and he jump into else.